# How to assert that all input fields are clear from a web page form after being reset?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, ruby

I am revisiting a page to create a new record instead of editing a record and I need to ensure that all the field values have been cleared out. (the page is shared between the different actions so I need to make sure the right action produces the right result).
How can I assert that all input fields are clear from data after reset (selenium-ruby-cucumber)

Comment: Seems like a good question which I've attempted to improve despite close squad mafia

Comment: How is this question 'unclear' ?  This question is like the definition of clarity

Answer (score 2):

Step 0. Set up Webdriver.

```
require 'rubygems'  
require 'selenium-webdriver'  
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
```

Step 1. Set a variable for finding values `found_values= false`
Step 2. Get an array of all the input elements `inputs= driver.find_elements('input')`

```
# all('input') if using Capybara btw
```

Step 3. Iterate through them, e.g.

```
inputs.each |field| do
  field.value <> '' && found_values= true
  break if found_values
end
```

Step 4.  `expect(found_values).to be false`

Note:

```
irb(main):001:0> a=2 && b=3
=> 3
irb(main):002:0> p b
3
=> 3
```

Comment: Hi Michael! How should your pseudo-code be treated? The line inside "do..end" looks like a pure logical expression (except "break") representing some boolean result, however "do" implies some action taken.  It seems here is a mix of conditions, assigning value to a variable and breaking the loop, however that is not obvious.

Comment: Hi @AlexeyR. Thanks.  Updated a bit,.  The && will get found_values set to true based on condition.  I moved the break to the next link based on found_values value

Comment: What if i want to assert without capybara?

Comment: that is just about using `all`.  Without capybara use `find_elements` as shown